# How to store/what to do with leftovers from Ayurvedic ginger & turmeric cold/flu drink?

Tags: culinary-uses, ginger

I've made an Ayurvedic drink for a cold/flu (though I adapted it to my tastes) - minced ginger and turmeric brought to a boil over medium high heat then simmered till it turns a dark amber color.

1. Can I store the leftovers in the fridge or are there any other ideas on how to store them?
2. What can I do with the leftover minced ginger and turmeric, which have been boiled and strained out?

Comment: It seems like you're really asking two distinct questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have made what is essentially an oddly flavored vegetable broth.   According to [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18628), that should last about 4-5 days refrigerated.

The leftover ginger and tumeric is going to have given most of its flavor into the broth.   I don't think you would *want* to use it for anything, although it would be safe to eat.

Comment: I never thought about looking at medicinal recipes as culinary recipes, even though that's exactly what they are. Thank you for the quick answer, info and new way of looking at cooking!